# Getting the remaining time for the next job to be executed in schedule package?

Tags: python, schedule

I am trying to print the remaining time for the next job. Here is some sample code:

```
import schedule
import time

def Job():
    #doing something...

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(Job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(schedule.Scheduler.next_run) # prints "<property object at 0x044FE7E0>"
    time.sleep(5)
```

How do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

This answer refers to the [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) package.

According to the [API documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-schedule), the correct API to call is the [`schedule.next_run()`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.next_run) method:

> schedule.**next_run()**
>
> Calls **next_run** on the **default scheduler instance**.

According to the docs, [`next_run`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Scheduler.next_run) is a property (`<property object at 0x044FE7E0>`) that supposedly stores the datetime object when the next job will be run. But you'll have to access it from the [`Scheduler`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Scheduler) *instance object* that's running your job. What you did was access it from the `Scheduler` *class* itself.

Rather than track down the `Scheduler` instance, just use the available API:

```py
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(Job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    time_of_next_run = schedule.next_run()
    print(type(time_of_next_run))  # <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    print(time_of_next_run)        # 2019-09-22 13:48:06.566073
```

Now to get the remaining time, you just need to get the difference between the date/time now and date/time when the next job will be run. Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module supports simple subtraction and returns a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object:

```py
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    time_of_next_run = schedule.next_run()
    time_now = datetime.now()
    time_remaining = time_of_next_run - time_now
    print(time_remaining)
```

That will print something like:

```sh
0:00:58.994702
0:00:57.994054
0:00:56.989839
0:00:55.987161
0:00:54.982645
0:00:53.980167
...
```

Take a look at the `datetime` and `timedelta` for more formatting options.

```
print(f"{time_remaining.seconds} seconds left..")  # 58 seconds left..
```